# I want to delete a file from particular location but its not deleting file from that location

Tags: java

I am trying to read content from pdf file after reading verifying content I want delete that file. I used `file.delete();` But its not deleting that file.

```
if(pdf.contains(text)){
    System.out.println("pdf pass");
    file.delete();

} else {
    System.out.println("pdf fail");
}
```

Comment: The pdf.contains(text) must be returning false.

Comment: may i know the reason...if i want check that condition then only it should delete the file

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the reader you used to read the content of the file is closed before trying to delete the file.

```
try {
        File file = new File("D:\\\\file1.txt");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        file.delete(); // This line will not delete the file
        reader.close();
        file.delete(); // This line will delete the file
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```